# Timing Hit type visible with out any implementation in DTM

Tags: google-chrome, google-analytics

I am manually testing the tags implemented using Dynamic tag manager.
I could see the Timing hit type which is not implemented by my developers.
For each page, i could see the time hit-type along with Pageview Hit type.
we are puzzled that i could see the unimplmented hit type only in my machine and that too in chrome browser only. But its not visible in anyone's machine. 
Has anyone faced this issue? Let me know please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot replicate the issue then it is environmental issue. i have faced the similar issue before

Answer (score 0):

Because this is not an error, as i could see this unimplemented hit type only in my machine, i believe this is environment problem.
Un-installing and re-installing chrome has fixed the problem.
I am not able to find the timing hit type now.